# How is the pattern used in medianBlur in Opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, median

I was reading about median filters in John C. Russ - The Image Processing Handbook, Sixth Edition, and in his book he describes the possible shape in the neighbouring pixels, which could be, for example a cross or square.

So I came across OpenCV [medianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur)  and was unsure about the pattern used. I would assume it is squared, but not sure. So what is the pattern implemented in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It is squared.